# Mysterious result from MongoDB MapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, side-effects

I've got a MapReduce in which the reduce function has erroneously omitted the return statement:

```
var reduce = function(key, values){
  var result = {apples: 0, oranges: 0};
  values.forEach(function(v){
    result.apples += v.apples;
    result.oranges += v.oranges;
  });
};
```

This code (*cringes*) has been in production for over a month, and we're only now discovering the bug. Why would this generate a value?

For clarity, the function above is missing `return result;` as the last line.

Comment: There is a tag for side-effects? With 8 followers??

Comment: I was as surprised as you are! I know it's not really a side-effect in the sense of LISP & Co., but I think there might be something funky going on that's unintended, but a known feature of JavaScript.

Comment: What's the value being generated by it? The correct value in `result`?

Comment: Can you show us the output, taking @Philipp comment I think it is not actually giving you the outputof the reduce but instead the map

Comment: So, long story short, this turns out to be a non-issue. The problem was caused by some git-spaghetti, and the return statement exists on the production server. The statement was lost in a merge, but the resulting bad code was never pushed.